# Opening new window or Message Box in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf-controls

I am new in wpf MVVM. i want to developed a simple application that have a login window and Main Window. When user can login success then open the main window, If user can wrong input then show a message box for alert

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem, and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views) link saved me a lot of time...

I forgot to mention, you have to use MVVMLight Library which also saved me a lot of code :-D

I hope I've answered your question.